# Creating A entry for server hostname and nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, bind

I recently setup a server with CentOS 5 32bit, Nginx, MySQL, PHP-FPM and APC. I'm currently working on setting up the bind server correctly. I'm creating my main domain zone and I wanted to know if I'm going to use for example domain.com, and want to use sub.domain.com as my server hostname as well as create my own ns1 and ns2 zones. Do I need to create a whole new zone file or can I simply add sub. ns1. and ns2. as

```
sub.domain.com. IN A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ns1.domain.com IN A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ns2.domain.com IN A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Or do I need to create another separate zone with sub.domain.com for it to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you not need separate zone file for sub.domain.com if you have `A` record in domain.com. 
If you need to **delegate** control of subdomain to someone else then you must create NS records for sub.domain.com and tell "who to ask".
If you have many host in subdomain (host1.sub.domain.com, other.sub.domain.com, and.other.sub.domain etc.) you can move information of hosts in sub.domain.com to new zone file and create NS record for it pointing back to your servers, but this is question of taste and need of order - it is not mandatory. 
You can find more information of this in [BIND 9 Administrator Reference Manual](http://www.bind9.net/manual/bind/9.3.2/Bv9ARM.ch01.html#id2546579) and in RFCs for DNS: [RFC 1033](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1033), [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) and [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035).